# How to save compiled underscore templates

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

As you probably know, underscore templates need to be compiled before usage. 
Now, if you have an application that uses lots of them, in order to render a specific UI composed of multiple so called partials, you need to compile all of them and this might take a lot of time. (Ref: http://underscorejs.org/)

Now, dust framework on the other hand has an optimization there, it supports pre-compiled templates.
(Ref: http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)

If you want to achieve the same thing with underscore, you have to find your own tools.

So far, I managed to fiddle the following code (tested in Chrome).
http://jsfiddle.net/GNK6M/

```
sources = $('script').map(function(i, s){
    return _.template($(s).html()).prototype.constructor.source
})
console.log(sources.get().join("\n"))
```

This code generates the compiled temples' source code and prints it to the js console.

Do you guys know better alternatives? The constraint is the templates have to be in underscore.

Comment: You don't need all the `.prototype.constructor` noise: ["The **source** property is available on the compiled template function for easy precompilation."](http://underscorejs.org/#template). So you can simply say `_.template(text).source`. That should be enough to generate a compiled template JavaScript object (assuming that you have a JavaScript runtime available during deployment) in the usual `JST` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have all the sources in an array (of strings), called 'sources',
(this can be achieved in many ways, not the subject of the question though)

```
var sources = [...];

var compiled_sources = sources.map(function(i, s){
    return _.template($(s).html()).prototype.source
})

console.log(sources.get().join("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using require.js you can use this plugin to compile and include your templates https://github.com/ZeeAgency/requirejs-tpl

Comment: I haven't tried it with a CDN but should be possible. You could of course go with what you've done, compile them once and then cache them so you don't fetch them every time.

Comment: So, the problem with this approach is that if you have the templates on a CDN, you can't do an AJAX request to obtain it. Unless the templates are JS and you can include them in your page dynamically.
This is another reason to use _compiled_ templates.